# os.walk() does not return filenames

Tags: python

I've tried to find an answer but came empty. I try to use `os.walk()` in Python but even if i have files in directories, it returns empty list. Folders structure is:

```
↳Photos
  ↳fold1
    ↳ file1.jpg
    ↳ file1.nef
  ↳fold2
    ↳subfold1
      ↳ file2.jpg
    ↳ file2.jpg
    ↳ file2.nef
```

my code is now very simple (dont mind creating dirs_path for now, it works as expected):

```
class PhotosCleanup(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PhotosCleanup, self).__init__()

    def create_dirs_list(self):
        for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(top='Photos'):
            dirs_path = [os.path.join(root, dp) for dp in directories]
            print dirs_path
pc = PhotosCleanup()
pc.create_dirs_list()
```

but filenames variable is empty. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Updated code snippet.

EDIT2: Ok, i forgot to paste acutal result of this script:

```
['Photos\\fold1', 'Photos\\fold2']
['Photos\\fold1\\Obrobione']
[]
[]
```

Comment: How exactly are you running the code?

Comment: Your code is not attempting to do anything with the `filenames` variable.  How exactly do you conclude that it's empty?

Comment: I've tried previously, but now i'm using debugger.

Comment: I get the results I expect with this: http://ideone.com/n8lLcD

Comment: I have had this problem on Mac Os, where the code I was running did not have permission to access the directory (see System Preferences -> Privacy -> Files and Folders).

Comment: Had same problem on Mac, fixed by editing file permissions for IDE per @rje comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your script file and `Photos` folder are in the same directory,or you can use :

```
print __file__
```

to get your current folder.

I suppose you're using a wrong relative path.Also you can try to use absolute path.Actually,the code works well.

Comment: They are in same folder, i mean, there is FileUtils folder, where Photos and script is located.

Answer (score -1):

You never gave any folder location, all you say is top=folder, which is not enough for os.walk to perform its duty.

os.walk(top='Photos'), add some address in this, it works.

Comment: I'm not sure what do You mean. It works for folders and subfolders, it just don't fill filenames variable with filenames. I've added actual output in question.